# Error when trying to play h264 stream with ffplay

Tags: java, video, ffmpeg, h.264

I have a file that contain part of raw h264 stream and I want to play it in Android app..

First I tried to play it on the computer... So I tried to use ffplay for this..
I used this command:
`ffplay.exe stream.out`
Then its opened a window and start to play it, but all i saw is a lot of green on the screen...

The output had a lot of red lines of errors:

```
[h264 @ 00000000031238c0] Reducing left cropping to 0 chroma samples to preserve alignment.
[h264 @ 00000000031238c0] illegal aspect ratio
[h264 @ 0000000003110ec0] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
Input #0, h264, from 'out4':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 1200k tbn, 59.94 tbc
[h264 @ 0000000005791960] error while decoding MB 50 37, bytestream -11
[h264 @ 0000000005791960] top block unavailable for requested intra4x4 mode -1 at 4 42
[h264 @ 0000000005791960] error while decoding MB 4 42, bytestream 4057
[h264 @ 0000000005791960] concealing 3519 DC, 3519 AC, 3519 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0000000005782840] error while decoding MB 0 3, bytestream -23
[h264 @ 0000000005782fc0] error while decoding MB 1 36, bytestream -16
[h264 @ 0000000005782fc0] concealing 3462 DC, 3462 AC, 3462 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0000000005782840] top block unavailable for requested intra4x4 mode -1 at 0 12
[h264 @ 0000000005490380] top block unavailable for requested intra4x4 mode -1 at 0 12
[h264 @ 0000000005490380] error while decoding MB 0 12, bytestream 917
[h264 @ 0000000005782840] error while decoding MB 0 12, bytestream 4415
[h264 @ 0000000005782840] top block unavailable for requested intra mode at 22 18
[h264 @ 0000000005782840] error while decoding MB 22 18, bytestream 1477
[h264 @ 0000000005782840] top block unavailable for requested intra4x4 mode -1 at 8 30
[h264 @ 0000000005782840] error while decoding MB 8 30, bytestream 4272
[h264 @ 0000000005782840] error while decoding MB 67 37, bytestream -10
[h264 @ 0000000005782840] top block unavailable for requested intra mode at 51 42
[h264 @ 0000000005782840] error while decoding MB 51 42, bytestream 3845
[h264 @ 0000000005782840] concealing 3309 DC, 3309 AC, 3309 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0000000005490380] concealing 3296 DC, 3296 AC, 3296 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 00000000057914c0] top block unavailable for requested intra4x4 mode -1 at 0 12
[h264 @ 00000000057914c0] error while decoding MB 0 12, bytestream 4371
[h264 @ 00000000057914c0] top block unavailable for requested intra4x4 mode -1 at 5 18
[h264 @ 00000000057914c0] error while decoding MB 5 18, bytestream 5007
[h264 @ 00000000057914c0] error while decoding MB 46 26, bytestream -6
[h264 @ 00000000057914c0] top block unavailable for requested intra mode at 37 36
[h264 @ 00000000057914c0] error while decoding MB 37 36, bytestream 1271
[h264 @ 00000000057914c0] concealing 2953 DC, 2953 AC, 2953 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0000000005791960] concealing 3391 DC, 3391 AC, 3391 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0000000005782840] top block unavailable for requested intra4x4 mode -1 at 5 0
[h264 @ 0000000005782840] error while decoding MB 5 0, bytestream 1025
[h264 @ 0000000005782fc0] top block unavailable for requested intra4x4 mode -1 at 47 30
[h264 @ 0000000005782fc0] error while decoding MB 47 30, bytestream 584
[h264 @ 0000000005782840] top block unavailable for requested intra4x4 mode -1 at 8 6
[h264 @ 0000000005782840] error while decoding MB 8 6, bytestream 4699
[h264 @ 0000000005782fc0] concealing 3600 DC, 3600 AC, 3600 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0000000005782840] top block unavailable for requested intra4x4 mode -1 at 0 12
[h264 @ 0000000005782840] error while decoding MB 0 12, bytestream 4586
[h264 @ 0000000005782840] error while decoding MB 58 19, bytestream -6
[h264 @ 0000000005782840] top block unavailable for requested intra mode at 44 30
[h264 @ 0000000005782840] error while decoding MB 44 30, bytestream 3906
[h264 @ 0000000005490380] top block unavailable for requested intra4x4 mode -1 at 37 0
[h264 @ 0000000005490380] error while decoding MB 37 0, bytestream 805
[h264 @ 0000000005490380] top block unavailable for requested intra4x4 mode -1 at 18 6
[h264 @ 0000000005490380] error while decoding MB 18 6, bytestream 4681
[h264 @ 0000000005782840] concealing 3271 DC, 3271 AC, 3271 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0000000005490380] top block unavailable for requested intra4x4 mode -1 at 53 18
[h264 @ 0000000005490380] error while decoding MB 53 18, bytestream 4391
[h264 @ 0000000005490380] top block unavailable for requested intra4x4 mode -1 at 2 24
[h264 @ 0000000005490380] error while decoding MB 2 24, bytestream 1268
[h264 @ 0000000005490380] top block unavailable for requested intra4x4 mode -1 at 0 30
[h264 @ 0000000005490380] error while decoding MB 0 30, bytestream 4550
[h264 @ 0000000005490380] top block unavailable for requested intra4x4 mode -1 at 0 36
[h264 @ 0000000005490380] error while decoding MB 0 36, bytestream 4722
[h264 @ 0000000005490380] top block unavailable for requested intra4x4 mode -1 at 0 42
[h264 @ 0000000005490380] error while decoding MB 0 42, bytestream 792
[h264 @ 0000000005490380] concealing 3596 DC, 3596 AC, 3596 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 00000000057914c0] concealing 3598 DC, 3598 AC, 3598 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0000000005791960] top block unavailable for requested intra mode at 25 0
[h264 @ 0000000005791960] error while decoding MB 25 0, bytestream 964
[h264 @ 0000000005791960] top block unavailable for requested intra4x4 mode -1 at 0 12
[h264 @ 0000000005791960] error while decoding MB 0 12, bytestream 4593
[h264 @ 0000000005791960] top block unavailable for requested intra4x4 mode -1 at 29 24
[h264 @ 0000000005791960] error while decoding MB 29 24, bytestream 954
[h264 @ 0000000005791960] top block unavailable for requested intra mode at 3 30
[h264 @ 0000000005791960] error while decoding MB 3 30, bytestream 799
[h264 @ 0000000005791960] concealing 3118 DC, 3118 AC, 3118 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0000000005782fc0] top block unavailable for requested intra4x4 mode -1 at 0 30
[h264 @ 0000000005782fc0] error while decoding MB 0 30, bytestream 778
[h264 @ 0000000005782840] error while decoding MB 31 4, bytestream -8
[h264 @ 0000000005782fc0] concealing 3600 DC, 3600 AC, 3600 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0000000005782840] top block unavailable for requested intra4x4 mode -1 at 4 6
[h264 @ 0000000005782840] error while decoding MB 4 6, bytestream 4729
[h264 @ 0000000005782840] top block unavailable for requested intra4x4 mode -1 at 0 12
[h264 @ 0000000005782840] error while decoding MB 0 12, bytestream 4431
[h264 @ 0000000005782840] top block unavailable for requested intra4x4 mode -1 at 38 18
[h264 @ 0000000005782840] error while decoding MB 38 18, bytestream 4798
[h264 @ 0000000005782840] top block unavailable for requested intra mode at 31 24
[h264 @ 0000000005782840] error while decoding MB 31 24, bytestream 752
[h264 @ 0000000005782840] top block unavailable for requested intra mode at 5 30
[h264 @ 0000000005782840] error while decoding MB 5 30, bytestream 3844
[h264 @ 0000000005782840] top block unavailable for requested intra4x4 mode -1 at 38 42
[h264 @ 0000000005782840] error while decoding MB 38 42, bytestream 3739
[h264 @ 0000000005782840] concealing 3291 DC, 3291 AC, 3291 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0000000005490380] Delayed frames seen. Reenabling low delay requires a codec flush.
[h264 @ 0000000005490380] Reinit context to 1280x720, pix_fmt: yuvj420p
[h264 @ 00000000057914c0] error while decoding MB 10 17, bytestream -6
[h264 @ 0000000005490380] left block unavailable for requested intra4x4 mode -1 at 0 16
[h264 @ 0000000005490380] error while decoding MB 0 16, bytestream 3934
[h264 @ 00000000057914c0] concealing 3239 DC, 3239 AC, 3239 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0000000005490380] left block unavailable for requested intra mode at 0 18
[h264 @ 0000000005490380] error while decoding MB 0 18, bytestream 3068
[h264 @ 0000000005490380] left block unavailable for requested intra4x4 mode -1 at 0 33
[h264 @ 0000000005490380] error while decoding MB 0 33, bytestream 745
[h264 @ 0000000005490380] left block unavailable for requested intra4x4 mode -1 at 0 38
[h264 @ 0000000005490380] error while decoding MB 0 38, bytestream 4460
[h264 @ 0000000005490380] concealing 2769 DC, 2769 AC, 2769 MV errors in I frame
[h264 @ 0000000005782840] error while decoding MB 79 24, bytestream -7
[h264 @ 0000000005782840] concealing 3570 DC, 3570 AC, 3570 MV errors in P frame
```

There is a problem with my source?
What can I do?

Thank you :)

Comment: Can you define what "part of raw h264 stream" means? Did you cut the file yourself?

Comment: No I didn't cut it by myself.. I just not really sure that the stream recorded from the beginning. There is a way to check it?

Answer (score 1):

It may be due to the fact that you are trying to play back **part** 
of a raw .264 stream.

To playback an raw .264 file the file should start with an SPS, PPS, and IDR frame (which has no dependencies on previous frames). If you are starting playback at some random part of the stream, then this won't work and the artifacts you are seeing are likely prediction errors based on missing reference frames.

Comment: Are you sure that this is the situation? Cause I use a sdk of some drone that give me the stream, and the widget in the sdk that supposed to play the video do it successfully :/

Comment: No I'm not sure, only you can verify if that is the case. If you've got the raw .264 file, you can e.g. open it in a hex editor, and check what type of NAL units the file starts with. If you receive an H.264 file midstream, you typically only start decoding the video at the first SPS/PPS/IDR NAL unit. Your SDK widget may be skipping other frames until then. This all depends on the content of your file. If you post your "partial" file online I'll take a look at it.

Comment: This is the raw buffer - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7sT67ga5GuwY3BfUzQ5SXgxdUU/view?usp=sharing

And this is the iframe for the decryption from the sdk of the camera.. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7sT67ga5GuwTFdlbldVVHB6Rm8/view?usp=sharing

Thank you :)

Comment: Your raw buffer starts in the middle of a NAL unit, and is followed by various NAL units of types "Coded slice of a non-IDR picture", Access Unit Delimiters, etc. If this is the file you're trying to play back, then it is failing as you can only start a "clean" decode from the next IDR in the stream. This would explain the artifacts you are seeing. I am unable to download the other file.

Comment: How can I find the next IDR?

Comment: Each NAL unit is prefixed with a 3 or 4 byte start code: in hex either "00 00 00 01"or "00 00 01". This is followed by the nal unit type indicator: in your file do a search for the start code and then look at the next byte. The last five bit of the next byte give you the NAL unit type. E.g. in your file you'll see "00 00 00 01 61". "61 & 1F" = nal unit type 1 (Coded slice of a non-IDR picture). You're looking for nal unit types, "7 (SPS), 8 (PPS) and 5 (IDR)".